# What can I use to combine songs?

Tags: software-recommendation, banshee, playlists

Sometimes you have songs you'd like played together - concept albums, songs which have a Part 1 and Part 2, and so on. Is there a way to merge songs in Banshee to achieve this? Or an option to always play a set of songs together? Or do I have to separately merge those files? In that case, what is the lightest, simplest software to use?

I'm looking for a simple tool. I don't need a DJ kit - just a merger, nothing more as I won't be using it very often.

Comment: Have you tried using the Playlist facility in Banshee. Add one or more songs to a playlist and save it?

Comment: I usually put all the songs I like into the play queue and shuffle it, so that won't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### mp3wrap

I found the software I needed, it is light, easy to use, and had only one function - merge mp3s. Great since I wouldn't be using it professionally or frequently

**to install, do**

```
sudo apt-get install mp3wrap
```

**and then, to merge mp3s**,

```
mp3wrap output.mp3 file1.mp3 file2.mp3...
```

Answer (score 4):

### Try Mixxx

As Banshee doesn’t have this capability

Mixxx is a lightweight DJ tool that allows for the playback and mixing of digital music (MP3, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC and Wave). It runs on the Linux, Mac OS X and Windows operating systems.

Mixxx has the ability to provide comprehensive support for any MIDI controller due to its scripting engine, and it ships with mappings for a number of popular controllers, a complete list of which can be found on the Hardware Compatibility page.

**To Install**

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mixxx/mixxx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mixxx libportaudio2
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a simpler tool? I don't need a DJ kit - just a merger, nothing more. I won't be using it very often. But I'll give this a try and comment on it. Thanks!

Comment: I found mp3wrap - it's a command line utility. Thanks for OpenShot, it might be helpful later, but right now, I need to manage my library and mp3wrap is perfect for that

Comment: Good your sorted

Answer (score 4):

### Try Audacity

Audacity is a nice program: It is very easy to use and even users with no idea about music and how to edit it can get used to it very easily!

Audacity can open music files and edit them, like cut/copy/paste parts of them or add some effect

**To Install**

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

[image: Audacity Screenshot]

In order to *play with* two files, do the following: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> so as to open the first file and then head to File -> Import -> Audio.

In order to cut/copy/paste parts, you have to select them and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X/C/V</kbd> them, so simple!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Audacity offered this, but I tried it and I prefer Banshee.

Comment: Ok, whatever you like :) But have Audacity in mind, it is a powerful tool!

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I'll see if I need it later, I haven't uninstalled it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat 1.mp3 2.mp3 > 12.mp3
```

`ffmpeg` also can do this.

Comment: It says I have to wait two days. And the concatenated file is a lot bigger than the one produced by mp3wrap.

Comment: This will change the whole format of the file ie. there will be an index at the starting point of the file and again in between which would create a confusion to the music player.